# If $f\in C(\Bbb{R}^n) \cap C^1(\Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$ and $\nabla f(x) \to L$ as $x\to 0$, then $f\in C^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous on $\Bbb{R}^n$ and continuously differentiable on $\Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. Moreover, $\nabla f(x)\to L$ as $x\to 0$. Show $f$ is $C^1$ on $\Bbb{R}^n$

I tried to use the limit definition of derivative which relates to the gradient, but it gets mixed up and confusing, and I sense like I underuse the fact that $f$ is continuously differentiable, and not merely $C^1$. I would appreciate a aiding line.

Comment: Isnt continuously differentiable the same as $C^1$?

Comment: I am not sure anymore. I mix it all up translating questions. I am sorry, I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Using mean value theorem on the defintion of derivative to prove f is differntialble at 0. Once is differentiable at 0, the continuity of $\nabla f$ comes from the assumtion of the question.

Comment: I get ${|f(h)-f(0)|\over |h|}\le \nabla f((1-c)h)$ for some $c$, but as $h$ goes to zero, the LHS is only bounded by $L$. Am I using the correct version of the theorem?

Comment: using L as the limit, $|{(f(h)-f(0))\over h}\ - L| = | \nabla f( (1-c)h ) - L| \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.